# Rsync permissions for webroot with non-root user

Tags: permissions, web-server, rsync, user-management

I'm trying to set up a non-root user that is able to rsync files to the webroot of our RHEL 6 server. I have a user set up currently that is in the apache group, as well as the wheel group (in order to allow sudo access per instructions [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_OpenStack_Platform/2/html/Getting_Started_Guide/ch02s03.html)).

I've tried the following, based on other posts I've found:
`rsync -azvP --chown=apache:apache img/test-image.png nonrootuser@1.2.3.4:/var/www/vhosts/test`

`rsync -azvP --chown=apache:apache --rsync-path="sudo rsync" img/test-image.png nonrootuser@1.2.3.4:/var/www/vhosts/test`

Without the `--rsync-path` flag, I get this error: `rsync: mkstemp "/var/www/vhosts/test/.test-image.png.0OU7WK" failed: Permission denied (13)`.

Adding the `--rsync-path` flag, I get `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`, and when I comment out the `Defaults    requiretty` line in `/etc/sudoers` as recommended in other posts, I get the `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified` error. It looks like there's more I could try to troubleshoot from here, but it feels like I'm going  down a rabbit hole, and possibly going about the whole thing incorrectly if it's this difficult.

So first off, is this setup of having a non-root user for rsyncing website files to the server common? Is there another preferred way of setting up limited access to the server for web development?

If this type of setup is preferred, any red flags on the configuration I've outlined?

Comment: Don't use sudo, set the correct permissions.

Comment: @IporSircer Can you elaborate? I wouldn't be posting this question if I knew what the "correct permissions" were.

Comment: add nonroutuser to group who owns /var/www/vhosts/test, then chmod g+rwx -R /var/www/vhosts/test

Comment: Thanks, @IporSircer, this is getting me on the right track, though I'll need to make some modifications to match the recommended permissions structure for directories within the site.